# WPF TreeView Items binding in ViewModel not working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeview

I'm trying to display a treeview in my application but somehow I can't get the binding to work and application displays a blank treeview. Here's the source code.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TreeViewTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TreeViewTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox x:Name="listbox" MinWidth="200" MinHeight="300">
            <TreeView x:Name="treeView" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=Regions}"
                        MinWidth="200" MinHeight="300">
                <TreeView.Resources>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Region}" ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" >
                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=(local:CustomerDataHelper.IsChecked), Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                            <CheckBox.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                </Style>
                            </CheckBox.Style>
                        </CheckBox>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Customer}" >
                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=(local:CustomerDataHelper.IsChecked), Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                            <CheckBox.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                </Style>
                            </CheckBox.Style>
                        </CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TreeView.Resources>
                <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
                    </Style>
                </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            </TreeView>
        </ListBox>
        <Button Content="?" Click="Button_Click" />

        <TextBlock x:Name="textBoxCrew"/>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Region> Regions { get; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string crew = "";
            foreach (Region Region in this.Regions)
                foreach (Customer Customer in Region.Customers)
                    if (CustomerDataHelper.GetIsChecked(Customer) == true)
                        crew += Customer.Name + ", ";
            crew = crew.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',', ' ' });
            this.textBoxCrew.Text = "Selected customers: " + crew;
        }
    }
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            Regions = new ObservableCollection<Region>();
            Regions.Add(new Region() { Name = "North", Customers = new List<Customer>() { new Customer() { Name = "N1" }, new Customer() { Name = "N2" } } });
            Regions.Add(new Region() { Name = "East", Customers = new List<Customer>() { new Customer() { Name = "E1" }, new Customer() { Name = "E2" } } });
            Regions.Add(new Region() { Name = "South", Customers = new List<Customer>() { new Customer() { Name = "S1" } } });

            foreach (Region Region in this.Regions)
                foreach (Customer Customer in Region.Customers)
                    Customer.SetValue(CustomerDataHelper.ParentProperty, Region);
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Region> Regions { get; }
    }
```

Customers.cs

```
public class Region : DependencyObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    }

    public class Customer : DependencyObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

CustomerDataHelper.cs

```
public class CustomerDataHelper : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsChecked", typeof(bool?), typeof(CustomerDataHelper), new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsCheckedPropertyChanged)));

    public static void SetIsChecked(DependencyObject element, bool? IsChecked)
    {
        element.SetValue(CustomerDataHelper.IsCheckedProperty, IsChecked);
    }
    public static bool? GetIsChecked(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (bool?)element.GetValue(CustomerDataHelper.IsCheckedProperty);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ParentProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Parent", typeof(object), typeof(CustomerDataHelper));
    public static void SetParent(DependencyObject element, object Parent)
    {
        element.SetValue(CustomerDataHelper.ParentProperty, Parent);
    }
    public static object GetParent(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (object)element.GetValue(CustomerDataHelper.ParentProperty);
    }

    private static void OnIsCheckedPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is Region && ((bool?)e.NewValue).HasValue)
            foreach (Customer p in (d as Region).Customers)
                CustomerDataHelper.SetIsChecked(p, (bool?)e.NewValue);

        if (d is Customer)
        {
            int checkedCount = ((d as Customer).GetValue(CustomerDataHelper.ParentProperty) as Region).Customers.Where(x => CustomerDataHelper.GetIsChecked(x) == true).Count();
            int uncheckedCount = ((d as Customer).GetValue(CustomerDataHelper.ParentProperty) as Region).Customers.Where(x => CustomerDataHelper.GetIsChecked(x) == false).Count();
            if (uncheckedCount > 0 && checkedCount > 0)
            {
                CustomerDataHelper.SetIsChecked((d as Customer).GetValue(CustomerDataHelper.ParentProperty) as DependencyObject, null);
                return;
            }
            if (checkedCount > 0)
            {
                CustomerDataHelper.SetIsChecked((d as Customer).GetValue(CustomerDataHelper.ParentProperty) as DependencyObject, true);
                return;
            }
            CustomerDataHelper.SetIsChecked((d as Customer).GetValue(CustomerDataHelper.ParentProperty) as DependencyObject, false);
        }
    }
}
```

If I add the view model ctor code in the code behind ctor and run, it works and I can see the tree view items displayed. Can't seem to figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: Why is the TreeView in a ListBox?

Comment: You are binding the ItemsSource to the Regions property of the MainWindow, which is apparently never initialized, and has no relation to the Regions property in MainWindowViewModel. Assign an instance of MainWindowViewModel to the DataContext of MainWindow, and bind like `ItemsSource="{Binding Regions}"`.

Comment: The ListBox is just a piece of code that I should have cleaned up. Anyway, your comment did the trick. Thanks! If you'd have written it as an answer, I'd have accepted it. I'm a little embarrassed right now. The improper binding was staring right at me all this while but I couldn't see it.